# Formatting MySQL data output

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am converting MySQL table into HTML table using [this](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_mysql_example__display_table_as_html.xml) PHP snippet, and it looks something like this [html]:

```
/----------------------------------------\
| Name | Subscribed           | Duration | <- Column names
|----------------------------------------|
| Bob  | 2011-08-20 04:07:01  | 60       |
|----------------------------------------| 
| Ben  | 2011-08-20 04:07:01  | 260      |
\----------------------------------------/
```

1. How can I output the table without column names? (Name, Subscribed, Duration) So that it starts from Bob.
2. Is it possible to convert that date into something like this: August 20, 2011 4:07:01?
3. Duration is in seconds, how can I convert it into minutes (Duration (s)/60) in PHP, so that it will show 1 instead of 60 seconds?

Comment: What have you tried? It should be simple if you are familiar with PHP and MySQL. For #1, try reading the snippet COMMENTS.

Comment: Unfortunately it's an article, no comment section :(

Comment: There are comments in the code!

Comment: [link](http://sameks.net/random/copy-and-paste-baby-clothes.jpg) *facepalm*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code, tailored to your requirements:

```
// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
echo "<table border='1'>";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $key => $cell){
        if($key == 'Subscribed'){
            $cell = date('F j, Y H:i:s', strtotime($cell)); // format date August 20, 2011 4:07:01
        } elseif($key == 'Duration'){
            $cell = $cell/60; // format time in minutes
        }
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";
    }


    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: @Shef is one awesome guy. I have got lots of help from him as well. He's a one in a million :)

Answer (score 0):

1.) Delete the for loop after `// printing table headers`.

2.) Use [date()](http://php.net/manual/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/function.strtotime.php) for the column "Subscribed" (second one if you use
[mysql_fetch_row()](http://php.net/manual/function.mysqli-fetch-row.php))

3.) Divide the third column by 60.

But I would suggest using [mysqli_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/function.mysqli-fetch-array.php) instead of [mysqli_fetch_row()](http://php.net/manual/function.mysqli-fetch-row.php).

Answer (score 0):

About the date, try something like this:

`echo strftime("%F %d, %Y %g:%i:%S", strtotime($v["datum"]))`;

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to remove the column names. This is the same snippets from the link you posted but with some lines removed. This will also print the duration in minutes.

```
<html><head><title>MySQL Table Viewer</title></head><body>
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = 'lptm42b';

$database = 'sphinx';
$table = 'spheres';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}


echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
echo "<table border='1'>";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $field => $value)
    {
        if ($field === 'Duration')
        {
            $value = $value / 60;
        }
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
</body></html>
```